# Why is the focus selection button not working on this Canon 5D Mk II?

Tags: canon-5d-mark-ii, focus-point-selection

On my Canon 5D Mark II camera, if I press the focus selection button the focus points show on the top display and you can set the new focus point using the top wheel.

On my friend's 5D Mk II, if I press the focus selection button nothing happens on the top display.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, is your friend's camera also a mk ii?

Comment: @mattdm, yep also a mk ii.

Answer (score 3):

Is is camera in full auto mode?  It needs to be in M, P, Av or Tv.

It may also not be enabled if in AI Servo (continuous focus) mode - *correction, it appears it is enabled, see comment*.

Comment: Focus selection is enabled in AI Servo, but I believe you're right about full auto.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my friend had made some change to the settings (though i still couldn't figure out which one) so that focus selection was controlled by the little direction nib right of the back display.

I only figured it out once i could ask him as you could only see the selection change through the viewfinder - it still didn't show up in the top display.