# Focus selection button not working

Tags: canon, autofocus, troubleshooting, camera-settings, canon-5d-mark-ii

*Why my top display is blank after pressing `AF-Drive` button instead of showing AF options? Is it possible to select AF mode through menu instead AF-Drive button?*

I have found [the same question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/why-is-the-focus-selection-button-not-working-on-this-canon-5d-mk-ii), but it doesn't have working answer. Due Canon's instructions, to select AF mode I need to press `AF-Drive` button and than turn the wheel.

The problem is that after pressing `AF-DRIVE` button in `P` mode my top display is blank. Turning selection wheel doesn't change anything. Like this: 
[image]

Before pressing `AF-DRIVE` button my top display looks as following:
[image]

Comment: Is there a lens attached to your camera in the photos above? If so, was the switch on the lens set to AF or MF?

Comment: @MichaelClark my lens is in AF mode

Answer (score 2):

The AF Mode (*One Shot AF*, *AI Focus AF*, or *AI Servo AF*) can only be selected in the **P**, **Tv**, **Av**, **M**, or **B** exposure modes. In the **CA**, and **Auto (green box)** exposure modes the camera sets the AF Mode to *AI Focus AF* and the option will not be changeable by the user. It should still show up on the camera's top LCD as the selected option when the AF-Drive button is pressed and an AF lens set to *AF* via the AF/MF switch on the lens is attached to the camera, though. Note that only some of the the Drive Modes (*Single*, *Continuous*, or the 10-second *Self-timer* choices) are selectable in the **Auto** exposure mode. In **CA** exposure mode only *Single* and the 10-second *Self-timer* are available.

If a lens is not attached to the camera, a manual focus only lens is attached to the camera, or an attached AF capable lens is set to *MF* (manual focus) via the switch on the lens then nothing will appear in the area of the top LCD for AF Mode, but the Drive mode options should still appear.

> Is it possible to select AF mode through menu instead AF-Drive button?

Yes, it is possible to set the AF mode via the *Quick Control screen (QCS)* on the camera's rear LCD.

Page 38 of the [*EOS 5D Mark II Instruction Manual*](http://www.tlu.ee/~rajaleid/manuals/Canon_EOS_5d_mkII_User_Manual.pdf) indicates that the *QCS* can be accessed by pressing the eight-way multi-controller joystick straight in. However, if you have *C.Fn III -3:AF Point selection method* (Please see page 198 of the [*Instruction Manual*](http://www.tlu.ee/~rajaleid/manuals/Canon_EOS_5d_mkII_User_Manual.pdf)) set to [1.Multi-controller Direct] the *QCS* will not be displayed. (That is the setting I have selected for C.Fn III-3)

To get to the Quick Control screen I have Custom Function *C.Fn IV: Operation/Others -3: Assign SET button* (Please see page 202 of the [*Instruction Manual*](http://www.tlu.ee/~rajaleid/manuals/Canon_EOS_5d_mkII_User_Manual.pdf)) set to *5:Quick Control screen*. When the camera is in shooting condition (a half press of the shutter button will get out of any menus you may be in) pressing the SET button shows the *Quick Control screen* on the rear LCD. Use the eight-way multi-controller joystick to navigate around the screen until the AF mode is highlighted. When the AF Mode box is highlighted moving either control dial (the *Main dial* is directly behind the shutter button, the *Quick Control dial* is the large round wheel on the back of the camera) will change the selected AF Mode. Half pressing the shutter button to return the camera to shooting condition will preserve whatever AF Mode is displayed at the time.

When in the *QCS* you can also press the *Set* button again and see a screen with all three options listed. Highlight the option you wish to select and press *Set* again to choose it.

Comment: I'm in **P** mode, and I turned on **AF** on my lens. But still in *QCS* I see only one option  - Manual focusing. There is no more options, after pressing *Set* I see only manual focus option

Comment: Have you tried a different lens?

Comment: no, I have bought the only one lens. Will check in the nearest service